# Where are libraries in the database

Tags: 2010

Where are 'libraries' stored in the database? Is that 'DirName' column in 'AllDocs' table, or something else?

(Doing some king of investigation)

Comment: Just want to caution you that any change to SharePoint databases might mean that the farm becomes unsupportable by microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only `libraries` name with SQL ,  You can get it from `[WSS_Content]` database at `[AllLists]` Table with  `[tp_BaseType] = 1` and for list `[tp_BaseType] = 0`

The final query should be like

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [tp_Title]  
  FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[AllLists] where [tp_BaseType] = 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this CodePlex solution- you can browse/download the code to get an understanding of how documents are stored in SP2010. (Not applicable for SP2013)

https://sp2010filerecovery.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

I found the location: libraries are stored in the table '[AllLists]', column 'tp_Title' is the name of the library.

Comment: this will get all lists and libraries